# Enviar valor de imput por JSP Parametro

Tags: html5, jsp

Amigos estoy incluyendo este código jsp include, para que en mi página se muestre valor, pero en parMontoTotal quiero enviar el valor del input txtTotal de la misma pagina, no se como hacerlo

```
 <input name="txtTotal" type="hidden" value="">


 <div id="divbuttonvisa">
   <jsp:include page="build" flush="true">
       <jsp:param name="parMontoTotal" value=""/>
       <jsp:param name="parMerchandID" value="602545705"/>
       <jsp:param name="parAuthorization" value="Basic aW50ZWdyYWNpb25l"/>
       <jsp:param name="parChannel" value="web"/>
       <jsp:param name="parMaxamount" value="1000.00"/>
       <jsp:param name="parClienteIP" value="190.117.255.189"/>
       <jsp:param name="parRecurrence" value="false"/>
       <jsp:param name="parPurchasenumber" value="84335"/>
       <jsp:param name="parMerchantlogo" value=""/>
       <jsp:param name="parProductid" value="Whatsapp"/>
       <jsp:param name="parUsertoken" value=""/>
    </jsp:include>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto se soluciona con Jquery. Yo haría algo así:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { // Cuando abre la respectiva pagina     
    $("#txtTotal").change(function(){ // Se ejecuta la funcion si cambia de valor el input txtTotal
        $("#parMontoTotal").val() = $("#txtTotal").val();// Y si cambia de valor se lo pasamos a parMontoTotal
    });
});
```

```html
<input name="txtTotal" type="hidden" value="txtTotal">


 <div id="divbuttonvisa">
   <jsp:include page="build" flush="true">
       <jsp:param id="txtTotal" name="parMontoTotal" value=""/>
       <jsp:param name="parMerchandID" value="602545705"/>
       <jsp:param name="parAuthorization" value="Basic aW50ZWdyYWNpb25l"/>
       <jsp:param name="parChannel" value="web"/>
       <jsp:param name="parMaxamount" value="1000.00"/>
       <jsp:param name="parClienteIP" value="190.117.255.189"/>
       <jsp:param name="parRecurrence" value="false"/>
       <jsp:param name="parPurchasenumber" value="84335"/>
       <jsp:param name="parMerchantlogo" value=""/>
       <jsp:param name="parProductid" value="Whatsapp"/>
       <jsp:param name="parUsertoken" value=""/>
    </jsp:include>
</div>
```

Primero agregas los ID a los respectivos input. Y en el jquery esta comentado lo que hace.

Espero haberte ayudado saludos.

Comment: lo probé amigo, pero no acepta poner ID al jsp:param

Comment: Podes probar con una clase sino. #(.txt-total)...

Comment: Gracias, si hice prueba y ya funciono